# how can I make a batch file create a batch file that can still contain percentage values

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I'm trying to create a batch file that creates a batch file, but as it seems I can't get the first batch file to also send over percentage value's (e.g. `%example%`). How do I make the first batch file, which creates the second batch file ? But the generated file should contain `%` ? Also if you find any other errors in my script please correct it :)

Also while I'm here, as you can see I've put an `"example, please help!"` underneath the `":prep"` I can't seem to figure out the ">nul" thing. No matter how many "^" I put it won't save to the last sector (which is "gnome.bat"). It will however save to the "setup.bat" but not any further. Please also help me with that!

The error is under ":Prep"

here's my full script: (not even close to being done with the script...)

```
@echo off
title Annoying Menu
mode 150
color a

:begin
cls
echo Welcome to "Annoying Menu" 
echo This menu is made to prank your friends
echo All pranks that you make on your friends are completely your own responsibility
echo Please be aware that this menu contains what could be consideret "Virus" 
echo No harm will however be done to either your, or your freinds pc
echo Please read through all the instructions before use, of the menu...

echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo 1. Please select a password to cancel the prank, by pressing "3" (only numbers)
echo 2. Please make sure that the setup files are ready to be transferred, by pressing "1"
echo 3. Now you are ready to send off the setup file to one of your freinds

echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo type "1" to create setup file
echo type "2" to prepare setup files for use
echo type "3" to download it on your own pc
echo type "4" to select password to cancel the prank (please only use numbers)
echo type "5" to test password
echo type "exit" to close the menu

echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo.
set /p opt= Option:
if %opt%==1 goto create
if %opt%==2 goto prep
if %opt%==3 goto UD
if %opt%==4 goto pass_select
if %opt%==5 goto testpass
if %opt%==exit goto end
cls
echo please enter a valid number to continue...
echo.
pause
goto begin

:create
break>"C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\setup.bat"
echo.
echo setup file created, please prepare the setup file before use, by pressing "2" in the main menu
echo.
pause
goto begin

:prep
@echo @echo off> setup.bat
@echo title quick_setup>> setup.bat
@echo color a>> setup.bat
@echo mode 150>> setup.bat
@echo :begin>> setup.bat
@echo break^>"C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\gnome.bat">> setup.bat
@echo cd C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup>> setup.bat

(Example, please help!)
@echo @echo ping localhost -n 2 ^>nul^>^> gnome.bat>> setup.bat)
@echo @echo set /a time=%clock%-1^>^> gnome.bat>> setup.bat
@echo @echo if %clock% EQU 0 goto Timesup^>^> gnome.bat>> setup.bat
@echo @echo :Timesup^>^> gnome.bat>> setup.bat)
goto begin
(Not Done!)

:UD
(Not Done!)

:pass_select
cls
echo Please enter a password that will be used to cancel the prank (please only use numbers)
echo.
set /p pas= Set Password:   
set /a pss=%pas%
cls
echo the password has now been set to %pss%
echo to enter a new password simply select "3" again and choose a new password
echo.
pause
goto begin

:testpass
cls
echo we are now ready to test your newly set password (if not you've set a password, please do so first)
echo.
echo type "1" to start the test
echo type "2" to set a password/new password
echo type "exit" to go back to the main menu
echo.
set /p lll= Option: 
if %lll%==1 goto test
if %lll%==2 goto pass_select
if %lll%==exit goto begin
cls
echo please enter a valid number to continue...
echo.
pause
goto testpass

:test
cls
echo please enter password to continue...
echo type "exit" to go back to main menu
echo.
set /p tes= Password:   
if %tes%==%pss% goto completetest
if %tes%==exit goto begin
cls
echo either you typed the wrong password or it didn't work, please try to set a new password if the same thing happens twice...
echo.
pause
goto test

:completetest
cls
echo The test was successful!
echo you're password works as intended
echo.
pause
goto begin

:end
```

Comment: Well the question is too broad and will be marked as such, but I am also not sure if anyone will help seeing as the script could possibly cause harm, even though your problems are really simple to fix.

Comment: Why is there a `)` to the right of  `setup.bat` ?

Comment: With the lack of specific questions with your code, you might need to look into asking the Code Review community instead of StackOverflow. Try breaking your questions down and only providing snippets of the code in question. You can provide the full code for context at the bottom of your post, as you already have done. Also, consider providing more context as to what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: To escape `%` use `%%`. And read chapter *Escape Percent* here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have percentages in your second script you need to put `%%`. Then the you will have the `%` in the output script:

```
@echo cd C:\Users\%%Username%%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup>>setup.bat
```

Escaping`%` with another `%` is a documented feature as described here in chapter *Escape Percent* : https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's your prep section rewritten as required.

```bat
:prep
(   Echo @Title quick_setup
    Echo @Color A
    Echo @Mode 125
    Echo :begin
    Echo @CD /D "%%AppData%%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
    Echo @CD.^>"gnome.bat"
    Echo (  @Echo @Timeout 1 /NoBreak^^^>NUL
    Echo    @Echo @Set /A time=clock-1
    Echo    @Echo @If %%%%clock%%%% EQU 0 GoTo timesup
    Echo    @Echo :timesup
    Echo ^)^>^>"gnome.bat"
)>>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\setup.bat"
GoTo begin
```

Please note however, that I have written the content as you had, *(other than using `Timeout` to replace the very hacky `Ping` command for your `1` second delay and my replacement of `Break` for `CD.` in creating the empty file)*. You will therefore need to account for the fact that your `gnome.bat` code uses a variable `%clock%` which has not been pre-defined anywhere in that code, and you need to be very sure that you're wanting to modify the content of the system variable `%TIME%`.